# simple check for dynamic_cast c++

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-cast, typecasting-operator

I do a dynamic_cast and want to check if the cast succeeds.

I am doing a basic null pointer check now. It like this:

```
A *temp_ptr = dynamic_cast<A *>(obj_ptr);
if( (temp_ptr) && (temp_ptr->some_function()))
{
      // do something if the function returns true
}
else
{
      // cast failed or function returns false
      // continue with normal execution
}
```

Is this fine or do I need to use assert ?
All I care about is that particular function. Is there any other check that I should use ?

Would it pass a code review ?

Comment: Its the intended use pattern

Comment: Only assert if it is an actual error for `*obj_ptr` to be anything other than an `A` (or a descendant).

Comment: note: `A*` on the left is redundant; use `auto` here to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The check of the results of the `dynamic_cast` protect the code from doing things incorrectly. An assert protects the program from programmers writing things incorrectly.

Whether you should assert depends on whether it is a mistake for an object to not be of the target type of your `dynamic_cast`. If coming into this code you expect a mix of objects, some of which are and some of which are not of type `A`, then an assert would fire for legitimate usage. If every object at this point is expected to be of type `A` and an object not of that type indicates a programming error, then an assert makes sense, at least in debug builds.